# If i have 4 xen servers in a HA with 2 NAS in failover over 2 locations. What happneds when the line between them is lost? and when restored?

Tags: networking, xen, nas

I want to place 2 xen servers and a nas in one building and 2 xen servers and a nas in another building. The 4 Xen servers would be in a HA configuration, the two nas would be set for mirror/fail-over as well. So if one building burns down everything will fail-over; VMs will start on the hosts in the other building, nas will fail-over. But my question is what if the link between the two buildings fail? The nas would fail over so the storage heart beat will continue in both locations. Would the 2 servers assume the other 2 servers went down since they can communicate with each other? Will both buildings start all the VMs? If so what happens when the link is restored?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `drbd` for those VMs then it's `split brain`.
So you should do [manual split brain recovery](https://www.drbd.org/en/doc/users-guide-83/s-resolve-split-brain)

PS:

If you haven't any arbiter then you would got [split brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-brain_%28computing%29) on network failures or hosts failures or etc.